# React funcional component calling function from another component

Tags: reactjs, react-functional-component, prop

I have two buttons named **selectall** in two different components . in Acompoent I am having **selectall**  button and its selectall function. I am trying to call this  selectall function from Bcompoent. Here Bcompoent and Acompoent has relation with Ccompoent. can someone tell me how to trigger selectAll from Bcompoent.

**Acompoent**

```
 selectAll={selectAll}

  const selectAll = (e) => { console.log ("selectAll")}
```

Comment: Please provide a more complete example. The code you posted is not valid JSX and does not show what you mean by BComponent and AComponent have a relation with CComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you will need to pass a method from your parent component to both A & B components like so:

```
class Parent extends React.Component{
 .
 .
 .
 selectAll = (data) => {
  console.log({data});
 }

 render(){
  return(
   <ComponentA selectAll={this.selectAll}  />
   <ComponentB selectAll={this.selectAll} />
  )
 }
}



class ComponentA extends React.Component{
 .
 .
 .
 render(){
  return(
    <button onClick={() => this.props.selectAll(data)>click me</button>
  )
 }
}

class ComponentB extends React.Component{
 .
 .
 .
 render(){
  return(
    <button onClick={() => this.props.selectAll(data)>click me</button>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
selectAll = (e) => { console.log ("selectAll")}

render () {
return(
<Child eyeColor={selectAll} />
)
}
}
class Child extends React.Component {
render () {
return(
 <div style={{backgroundColor: this.props.eyeColor} />
)
}
}
```

Or You can try this `<Child eyeColor={selectAll()} />`

Answer (score 0):

If you have reusable functions create another component with those functions (Util component) and export all the functions you need to reuse.

**Utils.js**  file

```
import React from 'react'

function reUseFun1(/*parameters*/) {
   //f1 body
}

function reUseFun2(/*parameters*/) {
   //f2 body
}

export {
   reUseFun1,
   reUseFun2
}
```

When the a util function needs to use

```
import  React from 'react';
import Utils from './Utils';

function Component() {
       return(
            <button onClick={Utils.reUseFun1(/*parameters*/)}> Cick Here </button>
       )
}
export default Component;
```